# VBScript to Find 1st link in a URL

Tags: vbscript

i want to do the following things using VBScript:

1. Open a URL

   strURL = "www.abc.com"
   Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
   objShell.Run(strURL)

*2. Find 1st download link in the URL which contains a string say "abcd"*

1. Open that download link

I have the script to open URL, so 1st and 3rd is done.
If anyone could help me with the 2nd Step, it would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and post your code for #1 and #3 so we can see what we're working with. Then we can tailor our answers to your coding style and structure.

Comment: I have added the code in the ques itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will launch IE implicitly (or whatever your default browser happens to be). It would be better to launch it *explicitly*, however, so that you can control it. For example:

```
' Launch Internet Explorer...
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate strURL

' Wait for page to load...
Do While ie.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

' Get all the links on the page...
Set Links = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

' Find the first link whose URL contains the text "abcd"...
For Each Link In Links
    If InStr(1, Link.href, "abcd", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        ' Found it. Load it.
        ie.Navigate Link.href
        Exit For

    End If
Next
```

Comment: i added strURL = "www.abc.com" then wrote ur code.  It shows Type Mismatch 'Createobject'

Comment: Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate www.abc.com shows error

Comment: You already had `strURL` defined in your code so I was just using your existing variable.

Comment: This code works for normal links. but doesnt work for download links. Kinldy help

Comment: I just tried it on `http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar501.exe` (WinRAR test download) and it worked for me. What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: The site has a download link , which when clicked , causes a pop up to open which asks whether to save the file. When i run this code, i m not getting that pop-up

Comment: What the download link? Can you post it here? Does it point to a static file or is it redirecting your to a download page?